# Cannot PUT error in Node with express and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

so im a begginner in Node.js and im trying to make a simple notes app with express and mongoDB, but im getting a problem at modifying one note that says "Cannot PUT " and the id of the note.

This is the code of the view of edit-note

```html
<div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3>Edit Note</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form action="/notes/edit-note/{{note._id}}?_method=PUT" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{note.title}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" name="description">{{note.description}}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code of the route configuration

```js
router.get('/notes/edit/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const note = await Note.findById(req.params.id);
  res.render('notes/edit-note', {note});
})

router.put('/notes/edite-note/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const {title, description} = req.body;
  await Note.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {title, description});
  res.redirect('/notes')
})
```

It is supposed to save the new note with the edited values and redirect me to the place where you can see all the notes saved, but it says `Cannot PUT /notes/edit-note/63dfae9a9b9b5575065eaaad`

Comment: Express cannot find the specified PUT url since there's a spelling mistake in `router.put` path: `/notes/edite-note/:id` should actually be `/notes/edit-note/:id`

Comment: Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was **caused by a typo**"

Answer (score 0):

Express is right, the endpoint /notes/edit-note/63dfae9a9b9b5575065eaaad does not exist. But this one /notes/editE-note/:id
Be careful with the typo.